# Allow Dropbox client permissions to delete but restrict windows user from deleting

Tags: windows, permissions, dropbox

Please can someone tell me if it is possible to achieve the following:

On a Windows non-admin user account with restricted file permissions is it possible to prevent deletion of files in Dropbox folder on the local machine?

Can I set different permissions for the Dropbox client so it can function correctly (it needs to be able to delete files as it does a create and delete with every file save)?

Comment: What's your goal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Dropbox using an account with sufficient privileges. Dropbox will function with the rights used that launched the application.

Dropbox installation does not require administrative privileges to work, and as such it will install to a location the user has rights to. This is usually their profile folder. If rights are not altered, dropbox will work correctly.

But you want to alter the rights, so what you also need to do is remove dropbox on their account, and install it globally for all users while being logged in with your administrator account. This way, dropbox will be launched at startup using the SYSTEM user, which has superseded rights over non-admin accounts.